# Search button on Chrome disappeared

Tags: ios, google-chrome

so Chrome recently changed the search button to a new tab button. I tried following the instructions in another post on this community which told to go to chrome://flags but i cant find the setting in it. Thanks for the help in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IjoW.png)

Comment: what is the textbox in your image with the magnifying glass icon in it?  isn't that search button?

Comment: @jmh That’s the search for the flags page. I’m talking about the one that used to be there instead of the new tab button